# Getting IllegalAnnotationsException in java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, rest, jaxb

I am trying to parse the string of xml file to java object, while executing the above code I am getting IllegalAnnotationsException ,I am new to this can any one help me on this?

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class RestClientExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String xmlStr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n"
                + "<Person><name>Pankaj</name><age>25</age></Person>";
        Document doc = convertStringToDocument(xmlStr);

        String str = convertDocumentToString(doc);
        System.out.println(str);


        JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(str);
            Person person = (Person) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    private static String convertDocumentToString(Document doc) {
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer;
        try {
            transformer = tf.newTransformer();
            // below code to remove XML declaration
            // transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION,
            // "yes");
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
            String output = writer.getBuffer().toString();
            return output;
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static Document convertStringToDocument(String xmlStr) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlStr)));
            return doc;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

The following is the person class.

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Person")
public class Person {
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "age")
    int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }



}
```

This is the Exception I am getting

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "age"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public int Person.getAge()
        at Person
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at int Person.age
        at Person
Class has two properties of the same name "name"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String Person.getName()
        at Person
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.lang.String Person.name
        at Person

    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at RestClientExample.main(RestClientExample.java:38)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@XmlRootElement` annotation will make the fields of the class into elements, there is no need for the `@XmlElement` annotations. [See documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement.html)